# Error al ejecutar ng add @angular/pwa dentro de proyecto Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, pwa

al ejecutar el comando `ng add @angular/pwa` en mi proyecto Ionic, me devuelve el siguiente error:

> The add command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a
>   project definition could not be found.

No tengo el archivo angular.json en el proyecto, no se si el problema vendrá de ahí.
Mi `ionic info` es el siguiente:

> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI          : 5.4.4
>   (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)    Ionic
>   Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.3    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
>
> Cordova:
>
> Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)    Cordova Platforms
>   : android 7.1.4, ios 5.0.1    Cordova Plugins   :
>   cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
>   3.1.2, (and 4 other plugins)
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res : 0.8.1     native-run  : not installed
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v10.16.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)    npm    :
>   6.9.0    OS     : Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

el `ng add` es para proyectos de Angular, y el tuyo es de Ionic

En todo caso primero tienes que **descomentar** la siguiente parte de tu `src/index.html`

(con esto le dices a Ionic que tu proyecto correrá en un navegador como pwa)

```
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
      .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
  }
</script>
```

En segundo lugar:
Asegúrate que en tu `package.json` exista en el apartado de scripts lo siguiente:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  }
```

en donde `build` es el script que ionic utiliza para *construir* tu proyecto como PWA

por lo tanto el comando que necesitas es:

```
npm run build
```

Y listo, ahora la carpeta `www/` contiene tu proyecto para ser desplegado en un servidor